# How do I get my example bodyparser working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I'm trying to send a post method with postman to receive some example parameters. However my example code won't recognize the `req.body` and so it is always empty.

This is my example code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body)
})

app.listen(2001, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 2001!');
});
```

If i use postman like this: 
[image: Click here!]

I always get an empty console.log

Comment: What happens if you remove the `app.use(bodyParser())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the arguments as query string, so instead of using: `req.body` you have to use `req.query`

`bodyParser` will parse `x-www-form-urlencoded` in your case, since you're using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: I tried req.query but my result is still: {} Edit: I forgot to restart my server lol thank you mate !